# How to check a string does not start with a number in Batch?

Tags: batch-file

How can I check that the first character of a string is a letter and so that it is not a number, or rather a cipher?  There are no spaces or special characters in this string.

Comment: Related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673711/how-do-i-check-if-some-string-starts-with-a-specific-word-in-batch

Your search string would then be something along the lines of `FINDSTR ^[0-9]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the simplest way:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set digits=0123456789

set var=1something
if "!digits:%var:~0,1%=!" neq "%digits%" (
   echo First char is digit
) else (
   echo First char is not digit
)
```

The first character of var is tried to be removed from `digits` string. If such a char was a digit, `digits` string change; otherwise, `digits` string remains the same.

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "var=1hello"

    for /f "tokens=* delims=0123456789" %%a in ("%var%") do (
        if not "%%a"=="%var%" echo var starts with a number
    )
```

If the var contents starts with a number, the token/delim management in the `for` command will remove it.

**edited** just to include the usual (included the previous code) and some less used options just in case someone is interested

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "var=1hello"
    echo(%var%

    rem Option 1 - Use the for command to tokenize the string
    rem            A dot is added to handle empty vars

    for /f "tokens=* delims=0123456789" %%a in ("%var%.") do (
        if not "%%a"=="%var%." (
            echo var starts with a number
        ) else (
            echo var does not start with a number
        )
    )

    rem Option 2 - Use set arithmetic and detect errors
    rem            This will fail if the string starts with + or -

    set "%var%_=0"
    set /a "test=%var%_" 2>nul

    if not errorlevel 1 (
        echo var does not start with a number
    ) else (
        echo var starts with a number
    )

    rem Option 3 - Use substring operations and logic operators

    set "test=%var%."
    if "%test:~0,1%" GEQ "0" if "%test:~0,1%" LEQ "9" set "test="
    if defined test (
        echo var does not start with a number
    ) else (
        echo var starts with a number
    )

    rem Option 4 - Use findstr
    rem            This is SLOW as findstr needs to be executed

    echo(%var%|findstr /b /r /c:"[0-9]" >nul && (
        echo var starts with a number
    ) || (
        echo var does not start with a number
    )
```

Comment: +1.But why you are disabling the delayed expansion? Is it really neccessary?

Comment: @npocmaka, under the stated *`"...There are no spaces or special characters in variable..."`* No, it is not necessary. But from previous answers, now i have the habit to define the environment behaviour just in case of ...

Answer (score 2):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET /a num=5678
CALL :initnum
SET "num=hello"
CALL :initnum
SET "num=4ello"
CALL :initnum
SET "num=hell0"
CALL :initnum
SET "num=he8lo"
CALL :initnum
SET "num="
CALL :initnum
ECHO(==============
SET /a nam=7654
SET "nem=hello"
SET "nim=4ello"
SET "nom=hell0"
SET "num=he8lo"
SET "nzm="
CALL :initnum2 nam
CALL :initnum2 nem
CALL :initnum2 nim
CALL :initnum2 nom
CALL :initnum2 num
CALL :initnum2 nzm

GOTO :EOF

:initnum
IF NOT DEFINED num ECHO NUM is empty, so it doesn't begin with a numeric&GOTO :EOF 
FOR /l %%a IN (0,1,9) DO IF %num:~0,1%==%%a ECHO %num% Begins with numeric&GOTO :EOF 
ECHO %num% Does NOT begin with a numeric
GOTO :eof

:initnum2
IF NOT DEFINED %1 ECHO %1 is empty, so it doesn't begin with a numeric&GOTO :EOF 
CALL SET "$1=%%%1%%"
FOR /l %%a IN (0,1,9) DO IF %$1:~0,1%==%%a ECHO %1 (%$1%) Begins with numeric&GOTO :EOF 
ECHO %1 (%$1%) Does NOT begin with a numeric
GOTO :eof
```

You should be able to get what you want from this demo.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off 
setlocal
set "the_string=a23something"

for /l %%a in (%the_string% ; 1 ; %the_string%) do set "cl_string=%%~a"

if  %the_string:~0,1% neq 0 if "%cl_string%" equ "0"  (
    echo does not start with number
) else (
    echo starts with number
)
endlocal
```

Another approach is with `FINDSTR` which eventually will be slower as it is an external for `cmd.exe` command.

```
@echo off
set "the_string=something"
echo %the_string%|findstr /b /r "[0-9]" >nul 2>&1 && (
    echo starts with number
) || (
    echo does not start with number
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `findstr` with regexp :

```
@echo off
set "$string=2toto"
echo %$string:~0,1%|findstr /i "^-*0*x*[0-9][0-9]*$">nul && echo is NUM || echo Is not NUM
```

in place of `echo is NUM` or `echo is not NUM` you can use a `goto` to redirect your script the way you want it.

```
@echo off
set "$string=2toto"
echo %$string:~0,1%|findstr /i "^-*0*x*[0-9][0-9]*$">nul && goto:isnum || goto:isnotnum

:isnum
echo is NUM
exit/b

:isnotnum
echo is not NUM
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work in your situation:

```
echo %variable%|findstr "^[a-zA-Z]" >nul && echo it starts with an alpha character
```

Comment: @npocmaka No, the `^` anchors it to the start of the line.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the string as a variable; in this way you are able to extract substrings from a main string. Here is an example:

```
@echo off
set EXAMPLESTRING=12345abcde
set FIRSTCHARACTERSTRING=%EXAMPLESTRING:~0,1%
```

The result of this short script should be `1` in this case.
Then, you can set a series of conditions to verify whether the first character is a number or not:

> if %FIRSTCHARACTERSTRING%==0 goto NUMBER
>   if %FIRSTCHARACTERSTRING%==1 goto NUMBER
>   if %FIRSTCHARACTERSTRING%==2 goto NUMBER
>   if %FIRSTCHARACTERSTRING%==3 goto NUMBER
>   if %FIRSTCHARACTERSTRING%==4 goto NUMBER
>   if %FIRSTCHARACTERSTRING%==5 goto NUMBER
>   if %FIRSTCHARACTERSTRING%==6 goto NUMBER
>   if %FIRSTCHARACTERSTRING%==7 goto NUMBER
>   if %FIRSTCHARACTERSTRING%==8 goto NUMBER
>   if %FIRSTCHARACTERSTRING%==9 goto NUMBER
>   goto LETTER
>
> :NUMBER
>   echo The first character is a number!
>   goto EOF
>   :LETTER
>   echo The first character is a letter!
>   goto EOF

Maybe this is not the most efficient solution but it works fine and it is easier to understand.