# How to remove BOM from output value

Tags: batch-file, text, byte-order-mark

I have .bat script that prints the value before the first equal sign into a .txt file:

**.txt file:**

```
1986=[TotalItemSize: 793.4 MB (831,989,085 bytes)]=[IssueWarningQuota: 5.039 GB (5,410,652,160 bytes)]
```

**.bat script:**

```
@echo off
for /f  "tokens=1 delims==" %%I in ('type C:\Users\edwio\Desktop\edwio_Test\mokedbi.txt') do (
    echo %%I
)
```

Because the .txt file is with BOM, my value output is always with unique BOM character:

```
'!1986
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you get `'!1986` output on running the batch file.

A UTF-8 encoded text file with BOM `EF BB EF` displayed as `ï»¿` with code page [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) results in output `´╗┐1986` in console window using [OEM code page 850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850) (Western European code pages according to my language and locale settings).

The text file encoded with UTF-16 Little Endian with BOM `FF FE` results in output `1986`. And if text file is encoded with UTF-16 Big Endian with BOM `FE FF` the output is completely useless without using command **chcp** to switch code page.

However, here is a batch code which removes all characters left to first digit from a string left from first equal sign.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "usebackq tokens=1 delims==" %%I in ("%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\edwio_Test\mokedbi.txt") do (
    call :GetValue "%%I"
    if "!Value!" NEQ "" echo !Value!
)
endlocal
rem Exit the batch file.
goto :EOF

:GetValue
set "Value=%~1"
set "Digits=0123456789"
:CheckFirstChar
if "!Digits:%Value:~0,1%=!" NEQ "%Digits%" goto:EOF
set "Value=!Value:~1!"
if "!Value!" == "" goto :EOF
goto CheckFirstChar
```

The subroutine `GetValue` removes the BOM characters from the value string.

See [How to check a string does not start with a number in batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25312333/3074564) for an explanation on how the check on first character of environment variable `Value` being a digit works.

The line `set "Value=!Value:~1!"` assigns to `Value` the current string of `Value`with exception of character at index 0, i.e. all characters except first one which is definitely not a digit. Run in a command prompt window `set /?` and read the output help to understand this syntax.

The subroutine exits with `goto :EOF` on first character in `Value` being a digit or if the string becomes empty in case of string left to first equal sign does not contain any digit.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this (if it works) is to add the end of the BOM to the `delims` list.  Run your `type` command, and copy the character printed out to the console right before "1986".  Then paste that into your source in the `delims=` line.

```
for /f  "tokens=2 delims==┐" %i in (mokedbi.txt) do echo %i
```

Then change your `tokens=` to 2 to get the next thing after the delim.

Comment: This was my first idea. But I dropped it as the output posted by [edwio](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5035880/edwio) does not look right for a text file with UTF-8 BOM. And second this solution depends on used code page in command prompt window respectively for the batch file. It works only if `┐` has hexadecimal code value `BF`. My solution is independent on used code page as using only ASCII characters.

Comment: @Mofi Agreed this is a fragile solution, but it has the advantage of being simple and fast to implement.  Yours is definitely better in a headless or production environment.  It wasn't clear from the question whether OP was going for fault-tolerant or fast-and-easy.